# GetStringAsync from HttpClient doesn't return anything C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

We are trying to get information from an API.
We use the following code to get an answer. It's a Xamarin Project. We are running it on an Android Emulator with internet connection. Android-Version:11.
When it gets to the line:

```
var result = await client.GetStringAsync(endpoint);
```

It just stops and doesn't throw an error. Why is this happening?

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Get = await AsyncGet();
        //await GetItemsAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<string> AsyncGet()
    {
        HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                    return true;
                return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
            return handler;
        }
        var client = new HttpClient(GetInsecureHandler());
        try
        {
            var endpoint = new Uri("My Uri");
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(endpoint);
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string checkResult = "Error " + ex.ToString();
            client.Dispose();
            return checkResult;
        }


    }
```

Alternative code:

```
async Task<string> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("My Uri");
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }


    }
```

This code does return the information but only in the console. When it is run with Xamarin, it also doesn't return anything.

Comment: it's probably timing out because it can't connect and you're not waiting long enough for an exception to be thrown.  Check the server url in the device/emulator browser.  Don't use `localhost`, use the IP/FQDN of the server, or read the documentation on how networking works in the Android emulator.  And be sure your server, if it is using the dev webhost, is setup to accept remote connections.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the code you posted reproduces the problem?